# How to attr class

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

I have a piece of code which someone wrote for me like this:

```
var $me = $('.me'),
        crazyNumber = 99999999,
        allOfYou = [
            { 
                elements: $me.parentsUntil('.you'),
                target: $me.parentsUntil('.you').parent()
            },
            { 
                elements: $me.nextUntil('.you'),
                target: $me.nextUntil('.you').andSelf().filter(':last').next()
            },
            { 
                elements: $me.prevUntil('.you'),
                target: $me.prevUntil('.you').andSelf().filter(':last').prev()
            }
        ],
        sorted = allOfYou.sort(function (objA, objB) {
            var a = objA.elements.length + 1 || crazyNumber,
                b = objB.elements.length + 1 || crazyNumber;
            return a - b;
        });

    $('#who').html('you ' + sorted[0].target.data('verb') + ' me');
```

In the end the `div#who` gets html from `target.data('verb')` I would like to get the class instead but I dont understand the code, I tried:

```
$('#who').html(sorted[0].target.data.class);
$('#who').html(sorted[0].attr('class'));
$('#who').html(sorted[0] + $(this).attr('class'));
```

And many other things, nothing seems to work (Im not familiar with Jquery target..)

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyqsW/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were near, replace your code this:

```
$('#who').html(sorted[0].attr('class'));
```

with this:

```
$('#who').html(sorted[0].target.attr('class'));
```

Comment: @Youss: `<div class="you" data-verb="found"></div>`, class for the div that has data-verb "found" is `you`, right?

Comment: Yes, change it in to something else and you will notice it doesnt work. You are getting class "you" from the first div

Comment: It seems to work...I dont know what happened earlier..Thank you very much:)

Comment: I once had a problem from copy/paste from stackoverflow..it turnd out some invisible red dots where added in the code, could be what happened earlier

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you are looking for this -

```
$('#who').html(sorted[0].target.attr('class'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/FyqsW/3/

Comment: which class do you expect ?

Comment: The class from the div that has data-verb "found"

Comment: `<div class="you" data-verb="found"></div>` the class is `you` the same returned by: `sorted[0].target.attr('class')` what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery object is saved into target.

```
sorted[0].target.attr("class");
```